# Create .txt file on a custom path (.NET)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, path, text-files

I have a program which use .txt files, but I want to make it work without having to change the path in the code when I run the program on another computer. When I click on a "create" button, I want a save as like window to pop up and ask me the path where I want to create the file.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Also provide additional details on the type of UI you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

or

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
```